# How to store and read data from Spark PairRDD

Tags: apache-spark

Spark PairRDD has the option to save the file.

```
JavaRDD<String> baseRDD = context.parallelize(Arrays.asList("This", "is", "dummy", "data"));

JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> myPairRDD =
    baseRDD.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {

      @Override
      public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String input) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(input, input.length());
      }
    });

myPairRDD.saveAsTextFile("path");
```

Spark context `textfile` reads the data to JavaRDD only.

How to reconstruct the PairRDD directly from source?

**Note:**

- Possible approach is to read the data to `JavaRDD<String>` and construct `JavaPairRDD`.

But with huge data it is taking considerable amount of resources.

- Storing this intermediate file in non-text format is also fine.
- Execution environment - JRE 1.7

Comment: You can save them as object file if you don't mind result file not being human readable.

Comment: yes, object file also fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing the Spark PairRDD in Sequence file works well in this scenario.

```
JavaRDD<String> baseRDD = context.parallelize(Arrays.asList("This", "is", "dummy", "data"));

JavaPairRDD<Text, IntWritable> myPairRDD = baseRDD.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, Text, IntWritable>() {

  @Override
  public Tuple2<Text, IntWritable> call(String input) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new Tuple2<Text, IntWritable>(new Text(input), new IntWritable(input.length()));
  }
});

myPairRDD.saveAsHadoopFile(path , Text.class, IntWritable.class,
    SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);

JavaPairRDD<Text, IntWritable> newbaseRDD =
    context.sequenceFile(path , Text.class, IntWritable.class);

// Verify the data
System.out.println(myPairRDD.collect());
newbaseRDD.foreach(new VoidFunction<Tuple2<Text, IntWritable>>() {
  @Override
  public void call(Tuple2<Text, IntWritable> arg0) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(arg0);
  }
});
```

As suggested by [user52045](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3187921/user52045), following code works with Java 8.

```
myPairRDD.saveAsObjectFile(path);
JavaPairRDD<String, String> objpairRDD = JavaPairRDD.fromJavaRDD(context.objectFile(path));
objpairRDD.collect().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can save them as object file if you don't mind result file not being human readable.

save file:

```
myPairRDD.saveAsObjectFile(path);
```

and then you can read pairs like this:

```java
JavaPairRDD.fromJavaRDD(sc.objectFile(path))
```

**EDIT:**

working example:

```java
JavaRDD<String> rdd = sc.parallelize(Lists.newArrayList("1", "2"));
rdd.mapToPair(p -> new Tuple2<>(p, p)).saveAsObjectFile("c://example");
JavaPairRDD<String, String> pairRDD 
    = JavaPairRDD.fromJavaRDD(sc.objectFile("c://example"));
pairRDD.collect().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: JavaPairRDD.fromJavaRDD can convert the JavaRDD with tuple to JavaPairRDD. Please find the source code https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/82701ee25fda64f03899713bc56f82ca6f278151/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.scala

Comment: I am getting the error: The method fromJavaRDD(JavaRDD<Tuple2<K,V>>) in the type JavaPairRDD is not applicable for the arguments (JavaRDD<Object>)

Comment: @VijayInnamuri I dont really understand what is your problem ill add working example.

Comment: +1 for the awesome answer. This works fine with Java 8 but not with Java 7.. Above error is due to this Java version compatibility..

Comment: @user52045 do we have to save the file using JavaPairRDD function? I'm trying to use the JavaRDD and iterate over it. I don't want to save that rdd in the system

Comment: @VijayInnamuri I am getting your error - fromJavaRDD method does not take the argument which objectFile method returns. Why this is related with Java version? I just don't see Spark has such API.

Answer (score 1):

Example using Scala:

Reading text file & save it as Object file format

```
val ordersRDD = sc.textFile("/home/cloudera/orders.txt");
ordersRDD.count();
ordersRDD.saveAsObjectFile("orders_save_obj");
```

Reading object file & save it as text file format:

```
val ordersRDD = sc.objectFile[String]("/home/cloudera/orders.txt");
ordersRDD.count();
ordersRDD.saveAsTextFile("orders_save_text");
```